# ios10 scenekit will crash when I click iphone's home button

Tags: swift3, ios10, scenekit

I playing the music in background with Third party Music Player, then I run this code in Xcode8, ios10. It work well.

```
let sceneView = SCNView(frame: self.view.bounds)
self.view.addSubview(sceneView)

let scene = SCNScene()
sceneView.scene = scene

let cameraNode = SCNNode()
cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()

scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
sceneView.showsStatistics = true
```

But when I click the home button, my app will crash and
I get this error: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'error 561015905'".

I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a SceneKit bug.

What you can try it to simply access [`scene.audioEngine`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1522686-audioengine) 
in order to warm up the audio engine (even if your app doesn't use audio).

Answer (score 1):

> 561015905 stands for the error
>   AVAudioSessionErrorCodeCannotStartPlaying. Apple Docs gives the detail
>   of this error as: "The app is not allowed to start recording and/or
>   playing, usually because of a lack of audio key in its Info.plist.
>   This could also happen if the app has this key but uses a category
>   that can't record and/or play in the background
>   (AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient, AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient,
>   etc.)." I am also getting the same crash when using lock button in an
>   app that uses SceneKit but doesn't use the audio.(From Comment of
>   **DancOfDeth** here: [What is Core Audio error 561015905 and why does it happen when I use the lock button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39568433/what-is-core-audio-error-561015905-and-why-does-it-happen-when-i-use-the-lock-bu))

It looks like a bug, see the bug report related to that at below link:

[https://openradar.appspot.com/28455923-SceneKit/CoreAudio Crash when device is locked](https://openradar.appspot.com/28455923)

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the exact same issue with

```
try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
```